Bessel Filter to separate AC and DC at Supply Level
I have a Supply Source composed of 150 VAC @ 400 Hz + 48 VDC. It is used to supply a big relay (~ 4 H, 1820 Ohm).
I need to extract the 48 VDC, filtering out the 150 VAC. I designed the following 5th order Bessel LPF

I should put this filter on a PCB with space limitation of 10 x 10 cm.
In your valuable opinion, is this a valid approach?
Have you suggestion concerning inductor types and characteristics?
Simulation TINA SPICE



That is an enormous load, I don't see that you have modeled the load.

Please, find attached the TINA-SPICE simulation for the circuit.

I don't see any resistance in this circuit; what are the source and load impedances? Or if you don't know, is there any way to determine them? And if not, must the network be designed assuming any impedance? How much attenuation does your DC load require, and what is the source frequency?

Details of your simulation and results are needed and, they need to be embedded in your question as images or similar. The circuit currently in your question is of no value whatsoever. Links that are needed to answer the question will break in a second or a month or a week and, when they do, your question also breaks.

@TimWilliams sorry, I though that src frequency was already posted. My mistake!!! I also added simulation. The source impedence should be few Ohms.

How much AC ripple voltage can you tolerate?

Is that link supposed to do anything without downloading it? Put a picture of the results in the question.

@Neil_UK the circuit is quite Large. It does not fit in the page. :(

@winny  less than +/- 1 V

Let me see, what else -- is this always-on, is it switched off (which will change the source impedance in that instant!), are there any transients (surge, ESD, etc.) it might need to handle, do you have budgetary requirements (obviously those inductors are quite large, and will probably be custom, will that be acceptable), and what height limitation for the PCB?

Your load is just 1.6 W @ 48 V. How about just a wide range (100-240 V) power supply with 48 V output and it’s job done? Are you allowed to load the AC part?

I should separate the 48 from generated DC+AC . I have no control on source @winny

Why? Is 48 V superimposed as control signal? If yes, extract just that.

@winny I don't know how the source generates the 48 VDC and 150 VAC@400Hz but I know that we should separate them. 150 VAC is used for other things, 48 is used to drive the relay. I cannot divide them before pcb. What do you suggest to improve the approach?

Define all tolerances and design a honking large LPF accordingly.

@winny but what do you think about the LPF that has been proposed in the question?

Can't tell. Does it fulfill your requirements? How does it behave for large step loads (relays)? How much margin do you have until core saturation? How much would it load the 150 V AC part?
